# Is there ctrl-c command in cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, kill

I have a process running in cygwin and using a port. When I kill the process in another cygwin window by issuing command:

```
kill -9 PID   or  /bin/kill -f PID
```

I can see the process got terminated. However, the port is not released. Usually I can terminate the process cleanly by using ctrl-c. Is there a kill command that can have the same effect as ctrl-c in cygwin? Thanks!

Comment: If the process is killed, the port will (eventually) time out and be freed

Comment: It seems like the process is killed. Nothing shows up when I grep it. But I can see it in Windows Task Manager that the process is still running. In this case, the process is java.exe. If I end the process in Task Manager, the port is released instantly.

Answer (score 3):

`kill -9` should only be used as a last resort. If `kill -SIGNINT PID` isn't doing what you want, try `kill -SIGTERM PID`. These signals can be trapped by the application and it can do what it wants with them including performing cleanup or ignoring them.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-C is a SIGINT I believe (signal interrupt), which would be equivalent to:

```
kill -2 PID
```

It's definitely lighter than a `kill -9` as it will give the process some time to clean up after itself.

For more info see [man kill](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kill&sektion=1).

Comment: I tried this command. It looks like the process is terminated but the port is still in used. Is there a way to make sure the port is released when the process is killed? Thanks!

Comment: Cygwin can still run batch scripts, you know :) Make your own kill implementation and add it to your path. In the script you can use something as simple as `taskkill /T /PID %1` @logoin